# MagSafe 85W weight

Tags: magsafe

I wonder if the weight of a MagSafe 85W adapter could be an indicator about whether it is genuine or counterfeit. I bought an adapter that weighs about 210 grams, whereas my old one (broken) weighs a little more, 230 grams.

I measured the weight with a kitchen scale, without the power cable attached (i.e. only the adapter) and **with the cable connecting to the computer on the ground**, such that it's (for the very most part) not included in the weighting.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you won't be able to prove it unless you had someone familiar enough with counterfeits to notice.

If genuine, it is possible that the power supplies are built by different manufacturers, or, as you've noted, that they have been changed (indicated by the different style of Magsafe connectors) which could have resulted in changes internally to the product. I doubt there is an official standard for these that would rule out a variance of 20g, unfortunately. This can be inferred by the following statement from Apple:

> A replacement adapter may not be the same size, color, shape, or
>   wattage as the original adapter that came with your computer. It
>   should however power and charge your Mac like the adapter that
>   originally came with your computer.
>
> [Source: Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)

Typically, a genuine Apple adapter would have the following:

- Apple logo recessed into both sides of the adapter
- A serial # for the adapter located below the metal plug used to grip the adapter head on the charger body
- Regulatory, trademark, and other information on the "bottom" side of the adapter

However, the above can all be easily faked. Unless you can easily tell that the build quality is suspect, generally the only way you'll know if it is a real adapter is if you buy it directly from Apple.

Comment: I can't upvote, so I'll say thanks by commenting: thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You propose an interesting data set that I have not yet found elsewhere, so I'll contribute my measurements:

My genuine magsafe 2 85W charger (included with macbook pro purchase from Apple store):

315 g = body + US two-prong wall adapter + charging cable

297 g = body + charging cable

259 g = body only (charging cable resting on ground)

My recent replacement purchase from Other World Computing (which they've told me twice is ordered in bulk direct from Apple):

261 g = body + US two-prong wall adapter + charging cable

244 g = body + charging cable

216 g = body only (charging cable resting on ground)

Both are manufactured by Liteon Technology Corporation and say 2012 (c) on the side.
That's significant variation between my two chargers. So either the OWC one is fake, or Apple chargers vary significantly, or they somehow get heavier with age?

Carl

Answer (score 1):

My 2015 A1424 Mag2 charger that came with the MacBook Pro 13 weight is a similar 320 g.  The charger's manufacturing date is 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Too light or too heavy an adapter is a very good sign it’s not genuine.

Nothing stops a clever counterfeiter from adding weights to a light knock off to defeat this countermeasure, though.